# How to Export SharePoint 2013 list images to Excel as Image?

Tags: sharepoint-server, custom-list, hyperlink, export, sharepoint-library

I made a list in SharePoint 2013 which contains a picture/hyper link column.
The Users need to export the excels but when they do they do not have pictures any more but they have links.
I looked after the way to not replace the photos manually because it is about 100 items! I saw one coding through internet but I didn't know how does it works.
I had an assets library as my images source so I tried to export the assets library maybe it works! but it didn't and  I had links.
 I decided to ask you professional guys to tell me your experience regarding export images to excels.
Regrds

Comment: Can you link the coding example?

Comment: Hi, I mean bellow posts! I found them but it is more use full in word and  not excel in MS Office 2013

Comment: this is the link for power shell code but of course it is for download and not export: http://adicodes.com/download-images-from-sharepoint-picture-library-with-powershell/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image store in a list, but Hyperlink or Picture column doesn’t store the image objects itself, so you are not able to export it to a excel document easily.

Here  are some posts for your reference:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/95527bfd-c6c0-4b26-8767-f3fba6da2013/how-to-embed-or-unlink-image-while-exporting-sharepoint-list-data-to-ms-word-20072010

http://cybertext.wordpress.com/2008/03/18/word-2003-unlinking-linked-images/

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/88e1b117-9ff2-4868-b490-4700d9cd6cc6/embed-images-in-word-document

Below are two similar posts:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/aed120f7-0f48-4b39-8063-416ed3858e35/how-to-export-sharepoint-list-data-with-images-to-powerpoint

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/11007c12-ab4b-407d-bc1f-9a90699f3a18/image-conversions-from-sharepoint-to-excel

I  hope this helps.

Thanks,
Gowtham

Comment: Thanks but do you know what are the similar step in office 2013:
1.Press Ctrl+A to select the entire document.
2.Click the large Microsoft Office button in the top left corner, select Prepare, then click Edit Links to Files (or press Alt+E+K). All links should be selected—if they’re not, then make sure you’ve saved the document as a *.doc file, OR select all the files listed by scrolling to the end of the list and then using Shift+click to select the last in the range.
3.Select the Save picture in Document check box.
4.Click OK.