# Export SharePoint List to Excel with Images and not their URL

Tags: excel, export, image, sharepoint-list

I have created a 2013 SharePoint List and need to be able to export / report on it using Excel (or any other output format). However, we have Excel 2010 and the current post below looks very impressive but deals with Excel 2013. Is there something similar you can use with Excel 2010?

http://www.sptechcon.com/news/sharepoint-dashboard-excel

The problem I have when I click on the 'Export to Excel' button in SharePoint, rather than exporting the image into an excel cell, it exports the URL into the cell. Can anyone offer me some assistance please?

Thanks in advance.

Kind Regards,
Confused SharePoint user.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint does not store image object in the list.. so you need to look for custom solution...

You should have searched first, similar question exists in Stack Exchange and is answered as well...

[How to Export SharePoint 2013 list images to Excel as Image?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/172114/how-to-export-sharepoint-2013-list-images-to-excel-as-image)

I guess this should solve your problem..